# Value does not fall within specified range error when adding folder - JSOM

Tags: javascript, jsom

I am attempting to use JSOM to add a folder to a pre-created folder within a specified library.  In the code below, I have checked that all of the variables are functioning as expected - meaning the library, the url, the arguments used as leaf names.  However the query fails every time and I get the error "Value does not fall within specified range".  The strange part is that if I attempt to add multiple folders, the first one is added, and the rest are dropped.  Any help will be much appreciated.

```
function storeFolderTest() {
    var curLibrary = empLib;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var folderURL = hostURL + "/" + "Employee Files" + "/" + "testFolder";

        var itemCreateInfo_subFolder = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        itemCreateInfo_subFolder.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);
        itemCreateInfo_subFolder.set_folderUrl(folderURL);
        itemCreateInfo_subFolder.set_leafName(arguments[i]);

        var oListItem2 = curLibrary.addItem(itemCreateInfo_subFolder);
        oListItem2.update();
    }
    context.load(oListItem2);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert('folder uploaded');
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reusing the `oListItem2` object for each new folder you want to create, try giving each new folder its own unique object. You can store them in an array like so:

```
function storeFolderTest() {
    var curLibrary = empLib;
    var newFolders = []; // <-- new array
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

        // ...

        newFolders.push(curLibrary.addItem(itemCreateInfo_subFolder));
        newFolders[i].update();
    }
    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.  I didn't set the url like you are, just the leafname:

```
function storeFolderTest() {
    var curLibrary = empLib;
    var l = arguments.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        var newFolder = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        newFolder.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);
        newFolder.set_leafName(arguments[i]);

        var newItem = curLibrary.addItem(newFolder);
        newItem.update();
    }
    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        console.log('folder created');
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        console.error('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
```

Unless you plan to use the newly created item, you don't need to load it.